# Jquery Dialog Ok button is not working firefox but working in IE

Tags: jquery

I am opening a dialog box with a button click event. Dialog box contains ok and cancel button. In IE it works normaly but in firefox dialog is opening 'cancel' button is working but 'ok' button nothing is happening.

Below is the code of a button in which i am opening a dialog.

```
$('#addImage').click(function ()
{
    var url = 'Default.aspx'; 
    var d = $('#dialog_img').html('<iframe id="ifrm" , width = 540 , height = 170></iframe>');
    $("#dialog_img>#ifrm").attr("src", url);
    d.dialog('open').dialog({ modal: true ,width: 560,resizable: false , 
        buttons: 
        {
            'OK': function() {
                 var img = document.createElement('img');
                $(img).attr("id", "dyndiv" + count);
                $(img).attr("width", 30);
                $(img).attr("height", 50); 
                $(img).attr("src", 'Uploads/'+window.frames['ifrm'].document.getElementById('dvFileName').innerHTML) ;
                var $ctrl = $(img).resizable({ containment: '#containment-wrapper'}).parent().addClass("resizable mydiv").draggable({
                    containment: '#containment-wrapper',
                    cursor: 'move',
                    delay: 200,
                    distance: 30,
                    opacity: 0.35
                })
                objid = "dyndiv" + count;
                $(img).css("z-index" , $(img).css("z-index") + count );
                $('#sel_obj_text').val("Image");
                image_visibility();
                count++; 
                $("#containment-wrapper").append($ctrl);
                $('#' + objid).parent().css("position","relative"); 
                $('#' + objid).parent().position({
                    of: $( "#containment-wrapper" ),
                    my: "center" + " " + "center",
                    at: "center" + " " + "center"
                });                   

                $(this).dialog('destroy');
            },
            'Cancel': function() {
                $(this).dialog('destroy');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please tell us if firebug shows any error on the console

Comment: given code doesn't contain anything about cancel button

Comment: Have you included jquery ui library ?

Comment: @claudio I saw in the fire bug it is showing error in "window.frames.ifrm is undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a semi-colon (`;`) after your `$ctrl` declaration.

In your original code, its this line:

```
var $ctrl = $(img).resizable({ containment: '#containment-wrapper'}).parent().addClass("resizable mydiv").draggable({ containment: '#containment-wrapper', cursor: 'move',delay: 200,distance: 30, opacity: 0.35})
```

In the edited code:

```
var $ctrl = $(img).resizable({ containment: '#containment-wrapper'}).parent().addClass("resizable mydiv").draggable({
    containment: '#containment-wrapper',
    cursor: 'move',
    delay: 200,
    distance: 30,
    opacity: 0.35
})  // <-- Missing semi-colon (;)
```

Comment: He doesn't want semi(;) after resizable, because he has done continuous operations[resizable,parent, addClass, draggable] on the div($(img)). Semi-colon is present at the end.

Comment: @Umesh: I meant after all that.

Comment: I saw in the fire bug it is showing error in "window.frames.ifrm is undefined"

Answer (score 1):

you should use `$(this).dialog('close');` instead of  `$(this).dialog('destroy');` so that the dialog is not created again and again when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

After clicking the 'ok' button, an image will be displayed in `'containment-wrapper'` created by block `$ctrl`. It works in FF, IE well. I am able to see this here. You can see in details with the help of firebug where the code is stopped. Given code is broken(as code is erroneous and complex here. `image_visibility(); count++` are not defined in provided code.)

Comment: image_visibility function is to control the visibility of controls in my form and count variable i have used to create a dynamic id . I saw in the fire bug it is showing error in "window.frames.ifrm is undefined"

Comment: Ensure that iFrame is present inside DIV with id="dialog_img". This iFrame is not accessible to your jQuery.

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand.See the second line in the above code where i am declaring the iframe.

Comment: As error is "window.frames.ifrm is undefined", you can check in firebug HTML tab. You will see, it is not present.

Comment: But in firebug it is showing div with id "dialog_img" containing frame with id ifrm